# Error Using sys.path.append - Function copies path incorrectly

Tags: windows, python-2.7, append, sys.path

I am having trouble using the sys.path.append() function. When I try to append a path which contains directories names starting with numbers the directories are not correctly named. For example:
sys.path.append("C:Postgrad\2015\Records\20150528\RAMP_UP2")
Returns:
'C:\Postgrad\x815\Records\x8150528\RAMP_UP2'
In the sys.path directory.

Is there a way to ensure that the path is correctly appended?

Comment: Use a raw literal such as `r"C:\Postgrad\2015\Records\20150528\RAMP_UP2"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how whilst typing my question. Just use a double back slash before directories starting with numbers:
I.e. 
sys.path.append("C:\Postgrad\\2015\Records\\20150528\RAMP_UP2")
Returns:
'C:\Postgrad\2015\Records\20150528\RAMP_UP2'